# Using jquery ui dialog to open an existing aspx page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make an aspx page open in a modal way using jquery ui dialog. I've come across this solution:

```
 $(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                height: 600,
                open: function (ev, ui) {
                    $("#myframe").attr('src', 'http://www.jquery.com');
                }
            });
        });

        $("#lnkCadastro").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog('open');
        });
```

And here's my div which contains an iframe and my anchor element:

```
        <div id="dialog">
            <iframe id="myframe" src=""></iframe>
        </div>


<span>Não possui cadastro? 
                    <a ID="lnkCadastro" runat="server" href="#">Crie sua conta</a></span>
```

My iframe div is inside a form tag in an aspx page. I'd like to show another aspx page in modal way when the user clicks on this anchor element. But i can't make it work.

I'm using vs 2012, jquery 1.10.2 and jquery ui (the latest version).

Is there an easy way on doing this? What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

It should be working fine

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/vuLTx/)**

Looks like the problem is you are binding the click event outside the `DOM Ready` handler.

**Move it inside the handler and should work fine.**

Comment: It worked! But Something strange happened: when the dialog appears, my footer gets pushed further down, creating a scroll bar. When i close it my parent page gets back to normal...what could be causing this?